# How can I print after a node another div element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append after the element div another div, but seems  it is not appending the element.

Javascript:

```
    const divList = [
        { divv: "Div-1" },{ divv: "Div-2" },{ divv: "Div-3" },{divv: "Div-4" }
    ]; 
        function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
            referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < divList.length; ++i) {                                                           
            let divi = document.createElement("div");
            let node = document.createTextNode(divList[i].divv);
            divi.appendChild(node);

            let child1 = document.getElementById("div3");               
            let child2 = child1.children[0];
            insertAfter(child2, divi);   
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="div1">
      <div id="div2">This is a paragraph.</div>
      <div id="div3">This is another paragraph.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's your expected result supposed to look like. You've mentioned you want "to append after the element div" but you have 3 divs in your HTML, it's not clear which one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var x = 10;
const divList = [{
    divv: "Div-1"
}, {
    divv: "Div-2"
}, {
    divv: "Div-3"
}, {
    divv: "Div-4"
}];

function insertAfter(newElement, targetElement) {
    var parent = targetElement.parentNode
    if (parent.lastChild == targetElement) {
        parent.appendChild(newElement);
    } else {
        parent.insertBefore(newElement, targetElement.nextSibling);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < divList.length; ++i) {
    let divi = document.createElement("div");
    let node = document.createTextNode(divList[i].divv);
    divi.appendChild(node);
    let child1 = document.getElementById("div3");
    insertAfter(divi, child1);
}
```

```html
 <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">This is a paragraph.</div>
        <div id="div3">This is another paragraph.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is not working, and it's printing in reverse order because it is appending each child after `div3`.

Comment: I copied, tried and it is not working and in the snippet, the list prints in reverse

Comment: I wanted to print in the same sequence as in in divList, means Div-1 first and  Div-4 last. While I was playing with it, I came to a solution, which is a simpler one. If you don't mind I can post it in the answer.

Comment: Yes sure. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const divList = [
{
    divv: "Div-1"
}, 
{
    divv: "Div-2"
}, 
{
    divv: "Div-3"                                
}, {

    divv: "Div-4"
}];
   
    for (var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        divLine.appendChild(newDiv);
        newDiv.style.margin = "30px";
        newDiv.innerHTML = divList[i].divv;
    }
```

```html
<div id="divLine" style="color: red; font-size: 30px; margin: 30px;">
  <div style="margin: 30px">This is div 1</div>
  <div style="margin: 30px">This is div 2</div>
  <div style="margin: 30px">This is div 3 </div>
</div>
```